# php unable to connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, extract-error-message

I keep getting this error message. What does it mean?!

[09-Dec-2012 21:44:32] **PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)** in C:\www\IT3126Prac\Project\try.php on line 5

[09-Dec-2012 21:44:32] **PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established** in C:\www\IT3126Prac\Project\try.php on line 5

Comment: check mysql_connect() parameters

Comment: On a separate note, the `mysql_` functions [are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php); please don't use them in new code.  Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

It means the user does not have the permission to access the database. The username and/or password is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Mybe you have written wrong server/host for the database

Answer (score 0):

Either the username or password is wrong, otherwise if you try to access the database from another server, there has to be access to remote access to the mysql server. Ask your database provider if they allow access from other servers, if they don't you can't connect to it. Try using 127.0.0.1 or the servers ip address as the hostname instead of localhost. Remember you have to connect to the database first like:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');
```